# WPF UserControl generic click event

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have created a UserControl in WPF which consists of 2 simple buttons in the first run.

Now, I want to display in a MessageBox the `x:Name` of the button which is clicked by the user, but I don't want to create a `Clicked` event for each button separately.

Is it possible to program 1 generic `Clicked` event in the UserControl and then identify the `sender` object to get the correct `x:Name` ?

Comment: You should have ask if you can send the button x:name as parameter to the command. I strongly recommand you to use the MVVM pattern.
See this advanced solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219361/passing-two-command-parameters-on-button-click-on-wpf-net-3-5-mvvm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing two command parameters on button click on WPF NET 3.5 MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219361/passing-two-command-parameters-on-button-click-on-wpf-net-3-5-mvvm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF How to know the current button pressed among multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566323/wpf-how-to-know-the-current-button-pressed-among-multiple-buttons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to program 1 generic Clicked event in the UserControl and then identify the sender object to get the correct x:Name ?

Sure:

```
<Button x:Name="first" Click="generic_Click" />
<Button x:Name="second" Click="generic_Click" />
```

---

```
private void generic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
    MessageBox.Show(clickedButton.Name);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer related to the question. Why many people wants to use some magic tricks?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [EventSetter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter(v=vs.110).aspx) for that in a style for a button.
Example in xaml:

```
<StackPanel
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="SDKSample.EventOvw2"
Name="dpanel2"
Initialized="PrimeHandledToo"
>
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="b1SetColor"/>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
<Button>Click me</Button>
<Button Name="ThisButton" Click="HandleThis">
    Raise event, handle it, use handled=true handler to get it anyway.
</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And then in cs file:

```
void b1SetColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = e.Source as Button;
    b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure);
}

void HandleThis(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled=true;
}
```